# Cassandra 1.0 Schema Agreement

Tags: cassandra

Im facing the following issue with Cassandra 1.0 set up. The same works for 0.8.7

```
# cassandra-cli  -h x.x.x.x -f RTSCFs.sch 
Connected to: "Real Time Stats" on x.x.x.x/9160
Authenticated to keyspace: Stats
39c3e120-fa24-11e0-0000-61d449114eff
Waiting for schema agreement...
The schema has not settled in 10 seconds; further migrations are ill-advised until it does.
Versions are 39c3e120-fa24-11e0-0000-61d449114eff:[x.x.x.x], 317eb8f0-fa24-11e0-0000-61d449114eff:[x.x.x.y]
```

I tried this http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/FAQ#schema_disagreement

But Now when I restart the cluster I'm getting

```
`org.apache.cassandra.config.ConfigurationException: Invalid definition for comparator` org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.CompositeType
```

This is my keyspace defn

```
create keyspace Stats with placement_strategy = 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy' and strategy_options={replication_factor:1};
```

This is my CF defn

```
    create column family Sample_Stats with default_validation_class=CounterColumnType
    and key_validation_class='CompositeType(UTF8Type,UTF8Type)'
    and comparator='CompositeType(UTF8Type, UTF8Type)'
    and replicate_on_write=true;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry found the issue, It is because of network latency schema agreement takes more than 10 seconds.
I hope that is the issue. Everything works fine in my local

Regards,
Tamil

Comment: No,the problem still persists. It worked it in my local bcoz I had Cassandra 0.8.6 Home in my path. So, It started 0.8.6 instead 1.0.0, when I executed cassandra in my Terminal. I hope this is really an issue to be noticed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got a reply from cassandra user group

It is a bug, patch is here

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3391

Until it is fixed avoid using CompositeType in the key_validator_class

I hope it resolved as mentioned in the jira

Regards, Tamil